# Prevent Chrome/Browsers from resizing/restyling form elements

Tags: css, google-chrome, cross-browser

Chrome has some cute features to make the selected form element (`input` ect) stand out like adding a border color and, more annoyingly, it slightly reduces the margins on some of my form elements after they've been selected, shifting the page slightly each time a text entry box is selected.

It's not the `textarea` draggable resize effect that chrome has, it's effecting input elements that should have a constant size, but they automatically change once selected.

Is there any CSS to disable this feature, or do I simply have to make sure my text box margins/padding are set up such that Chrome doesn't resize them?

Comment: you can make 'em with fixed size using style

Comment: Can you reproduce the problem? http://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: @thirtydot thanks for the suggestion, that's an awesome site! Oddly enough I _can't_ reproduce it though, even using the full CSS and HTML from the page! I'll have to look more into it myself.

Comment: Try here instead: http://jsbin.com/. jsFiddle's boilerplate can sometimes cause problems.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I love working on other people's sites...the problem was javascript they were using to restyle form elements after click and I have no idea why. Solution was to remove that junk.

Answer (score 0):

Here it is

```
textarea { resize:none; }
```

Comment: I set the property and Inspect Element confirms `resize:none` is being applied, yet the changes still occur (text box and layout shrink slightly). Might it be anything else?

Comment: On second thought I should have clarified; this isn't about the little draggable thing on text areas, these are just inputs.